# Sum up arrays isn't summing correctly - C language

Tags: arrays, c, sum

I had homework assigned to save either 0 or 1 in two arrays, calculate the sum as they were binary numbers and return the result, just like you would do by hand, but the sum of is wrong, here is a little example of inputs and outputs:

```
//Input example -> num1[] = {0,1}; num2[] = {0,1}
//Result I want to get = 1,0
//Result I get = 0, 0
```

Here´s the code of the sum part

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int leave = 0, input;
  int num1[9], num2[8], result[12], carry = 0, i, i2;

   //Getting inputs
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
     printf("Type 0 or 1 to save in position %d of num1\n", i + 1);
     scanf("%d", &num1[i]);

     //Condition to exit the loop
     if (num1[i] > 1 || num1[i] < 0) {
       num1[i] = 0;
       printf("Exiting loop...\n");
       break;
     }
   }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      printf("Type 0 or 1 to save in position %d of num2\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%d", &num2[i]);

     //Condition to exit the loop
      if (num2[i] > 1 || num2[i] < 0) {
        num2[i] = 0;
        printf("Exiting loop...\n");
        break;
      }
    }

    //Sum of arrays
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < i; i2++) {
      if (num1[i2] == 1 && num2[i2] == 1) {
        if (carry== 1) {
          result[i2] = 1;
        } else {
          result[i2] = 0;
          carry = 1;
        }
      } else {
        result[i2] = carry + num1[i2] + num2[i2];
        carry = 0;
      }
    }
  
    //Showing results
    for (i2 = 0; i2 <= i; i2++) {
      printf("%d", result[i2]);
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Out of bounds on num2

Comment: Uninitialized values in num1 and num2 when you do sum.

Comment: The condition `num1[i] > 1 || num1[i] < 0` is really equivalent to `num1[i] != 1 && num1[i] != 0`. The latter is much clearer to understand.

Comment: @stark Out of bounds? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Fix your range for `num2`? If you access `num2[i]` make sure, `i` only goes up to 7.

Comment: `resto` is used but not declared anywhere?

Comment: @psmears Sorry, I was translating it to english and forgot to change it. resto is carry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Boundary exceed**
`C` doesn't check for bounds or boundary and not even gives you a ⚠ warning.
you have declared `num2[8]` that has reserved memory for 8 integer elements
but you are explicitly giving it `9` elements to store through

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      printf("Type 0 or 1 to save in position %d of num2\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%d", &num2[i]);
```

that results to overwrite an other memory address' value that can cause disfunction to your program.(In my case `num1[0]` was overwritten)
So declare enough elements to work with arrays.
**2.**
In this fragment

```
else {
        result[i2] = carry + num1[i2] + num2[i2];
        carry = 0;
```

if you encounter  `carry` as `1` and (`num1` or `num2`) as `1` this would lead you to wrong calculation.
So add some more instructions to counter it.
**3.**
Remove `=` from `<=`

```
//Showing results
    for (i2 = 0; i2 <= i; i2++) {
      printf("%d", result[i2]);
    }
```

to get result without printing a garbage value at the end. because `result[9]` has not assigned a value explicitly.